# Regex routes for public assets

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, express

I have "widgets" which include both client & and server `.coffee` files (think of client as a Backbone.js model/view and server as the correlating ExpressJS routes), all under the root project:

```
my-node-expressjs3-project/
  src/
    widget1/
      client/
        app.coffee
      server/
        routes.coffee
    widget2/
      client/
        app.coffee
      server/
        routes.coffee
  app/
    widget1/
      client/
        app.js 
      server/
        routes.js
    widget2/
      client/
        app.js 
      server/
        routes.js
  public/
```

All `.coffee` files compile to `app/`. I am trying to keep the widgets referentially intact, and just allow the `client/` folder to be served for "widgets". Problem 1 - I can't get it to work. Problem 2 - if 2 widgets contain the same `app.js` file, they would appear the same under the way I thought to solve the problem:

```
app.use express['static'](__dirname + '/public')
app.use express['static'](__dirname + '/app/*/client/')
```

How would I do this?

Comment: If you always need all the widgets for your site it is better to compile those into 1 file. This will solve your second problem and is good for page loading time.

Comment: I don't always need them. They are widgets for that reason! Good suggestion, though. Wonder if I could make a `cake` reference to a declared widget inclusion or something. Still, seems like this should be doable in some other sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding problem one, node doesn't have a built-in way to search a filesystem like this using globbing.  If you have non-widgety things in your app directory you will need to filter them out manually, or you can use something like the awesome [node-findit](https://github.com/substack/node-findit) package.

Regarding problem two, once you have the list of widgets, you can just mount the static middleware at that subUrl for each widget.  The `app.use` function takes an optional mount path.

```
var widgetDirs = fs.readdirSync('app');

widgetDirs.forEach(function(widgetDir) {
    app.use(widgetDir, express.static(__dirname + '/app/' + widgetDir + '/client/'));
});
```